# Amazon Alexa Device Discovery for Smart Home API with Lambda Failing

Tags: aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit, amazon-echo

I have setup an Alexa Smart Home Skill, all settings done, oauth2 processed done and skill is enabled on my Amazon Echo device. Lambda function is setup and linked to the skill. When I "Discover Devices" I can see the payload hit my Lambda function in the log. I am literally returning via the context.succeed() method the following JSON with a test appliance. However Echo tells me that it fails to find any devices.

```
{
  "header": {
    "messageId": "42e0bf9c-18e2-424f-bb11-f8a12df1a79e",
    "name": "DiscoverAppliancesResponse",
    "namespace": "Alexa.ConnectedHome.Discovery",
    "payloadVersion": "2"
  },
  "payload": {
    "discoveredAppliances": [
      {
        "actions": [
          "incrementPercentage",
          "decrementPercentage",
          "setPercentage",
          "turnOn",
          "turnOff"
        ],
        "applianceId": "0d6884ab-030e-8ff4-ffffaa15c06e0453",
        "friendlyDescription": "Study Light connected to Loxone Kit",
        "friendlyName": "Study Light",
        "isReachable": true,
        "manufacturerName": "Loxone",
        "modelName": "Spot"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Does the above payload look correct?

Comment: Have you managed to make it work? I'm facing the exact same issue. I already tried generating a true random messageId, and changing other values just in case, but noghing :(

Comment: I've just made min work! In my case, I had `name` and `namespace` values mixed up. Unfortunately I have to say that now my response looks just like yours... I think the lacking of a good debugging tool on Alexa's side makes it harder to find this minor mistakes....

Answer (score 2):

According to https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/docs/smart-home-skill-api-reference#discovery-messages the `version` attribute is required. Your response seems to be missing that attribute.

In my (very short) experience with this, even the smallest mistake in the response would generate a silent error like the one you are experiencing.

Comment: The version is certainly missing.

Comment: Domotics, IoT and Batman are certainly also on-topic on the new IoT.SE (https://iot.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. If you are creating discovery for "Entertainment Device", make sure you have wrapped the output in 'event' key for context.succeed

```
var payload = {
    endpoints:
        [
            {
                "endpointId": "My-id",
                "manufacturerName": "Manufacturer",
                "friendlyName": "Living room TV",
                "description": "65in LED TV from Demo AV Company",
                "displayCategories": [  ],
                "cookie": {
                    "data": "e.g. ip address",
                },
                "capabilities":
                    [

                        {
                            "interface": "Alexa.Speaker",
                            "version": "1.0",
                            "type": "AlexaInterface"
                        },

                    ]
            }
        ]
};
var header = request.directive.header;
header.name = "Discover.Response";
context.succeed({ event: {
    header: header, payload: payload
} });
```

Although, in the sample code, this is never mentioned and an incorrect example is given (https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/docs/steps-to-create-a-smart-home-skill). However, the response body provided includes the "event" key.

Comment: This is still true, stumped me for about 2 hours, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Answer was wrong. Only useful information was this

This context.fail syntax is actually deprecated. Look up the Lambda context object properties, it should look more like "callback(null, resultObj)" now.

Comment: do you have any proof links? As I see, there are lots of examples where result is returned as a parameter of `context.succeed` function. Moreover, in Smart Home API, there is no callback method passed to intent handler in skill.

Comment: No, my answer is actually wrong. I misunderstood something. All you need is the callback function. I've since edited it

Answer (score 0):

Recreating lambda function helped me fix the issue. I also set "Enable trigger" check button while creating, though I'm not sure if that matters. After that my device provided by skill was found successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Did you include the `return` statement in your function?

```
    return {
        "header": header,
        "payload": payload
    }
```

It was missing in the example and after adding it, I was able to 'discover' my device.

Comment: Since the question refers to the JSON this is not applicable as both header and payload are in there.